# what is this "/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=62"

Tags: php

I'm a new comer in web development, so I would like to clarify one doubt, I have found some websites URL part like `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=62` . What is this mean by in php web pages and how to get updating the index.php web page with different contents while clicking on different menu items. I know how to pas arguments while calling a URL, but my doubt is in `option=com_content&view=article`. Please clarify my doubt. Please give more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are variables which will appear in the [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array (and often the [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  array -- `$_REQUEST` *usually* contains everything that `$_GET` does, but there are some [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)). They are normally (but not always) put there by a form with "get" as the method attribute in HTML or they are put there in some anchor href attribute directly.

If you have `option=com_content&view=article`, then `$_GET['option']` will equal "com_content" and `$_GET['view']` will equal "article"

If you're interested in learning more, I recommend the [tizag tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php), which goes into a little more depth than I have.

Comment: Do you think, those web pages contents are loading from database using those variables as a condition?

Comment: A lot of people will do that, but it could be that there are flat files simply being included, or they could be used to render some other data. Basically, it could be anything.

Comment: which is the good practice, the contents kept it in XML file or flat file?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

those are URL variables, they are variables you can pass to a page via the URL *fancy that*

[PHP.NET](http://php.net/) <-- this is the best php resource (imo). good place to start. specifically look in [Predefined Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) for the $_REQUEST/$_GET server variables, which is what your question is dancing around.

You may also want to read [W3Schools PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) [EDIT:: apperently this is not a good place to start. still, get a good tutorial on php and the rest can be found @ php.net

and to the rest.. how about we provide a better tutorial to start... 
I learned from (a very antiquated) oreilly php book - you can get the latest @ http://oreilly.com/php/

Comment: Don't read the W3Schools PHP tutorial. It is awful and doesn't mention the gaping wide security holes it has in just about every example that could have a security hole.

Comment: judging by the question, I still think it's a good place for the absolute beginner to learn. php.net is overwhelming if you don't already have some basics.

Comment: @rlemen If you yourself will have a look at w3fools.com, you'll know why w3schools is **not** *a good place for the absolute beginner to learn* anything.